Fake game wardens capture a couple camping
This may be a Lifetime Original or a similar type of movie.  
It opens up with a man and woman camping in the woods.  They are sleeping when headlights suddenly shine on them.  The outlines of two people claiming to be game wardens or rangers order them to stay on the ground.  (The game wardens are actually a husband and wife that are criminals.) 
While one holds a gun the other handcuffs or ties up the campers and they are taken captive.  Eventually the male camper is killed and the female forced to travel deeper and deeper into a remote area with the criminals.  
The captured woman is younger and prettier than the male criminal's wife and he becomes attracted to her.  The wife naturally becomes jealous and helps the pretty camper escape.  
This movie may be 15-25 years old.

That might be:  Terror in the Night (1994 TV Movie)
The movie's summary is very brief:

A fugitive killer posing as a policeman arrests two campers in the
  Arizona mountains.

Here's a full video, the camping scene that you mention starts at 17:25:
(there are two people present when the campers are captured)



Movie poster:


You are correct, the movie is Terror in the Night!  It appears that my description was a little off but accurate enough for you to figure out.  Thanks so much!!!

@Bluejoe: No problem! ... Please consider accepting the answer.

Roger that.  I'm new to this forum so I'm still learning the rules.  :)
